# Handling Orientation in Windows 8.1 Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, visualstatemanager

I am making a Win Store App, and facing the issue to handle orientation.

There is a grid, I want to modify the design of it when the orientation is changed.
The stack Panels in both the sides (in Landscape View) should goto Top and Bottom in Portrait View.

Currently I have created two grids with all the controls and adjust them according to the orientation, and switching the visibility property, using VisualStateManager.

But I want to achieve this with a single grid, any suggestion will be a great help for me.

The below image is the concept design of the app:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing this with a single Grid is difficult, but possible.

Firstly, what you probably want to do is worry less about orientation and more about horizontal width. That way, if the user snaps the app in such a way that there isn't much horizontal space (similar to portrait mode), you can display a similar experience.

Now, onto the Grid.

The key here is that you are moving from a `Grid` with, in essence, 3 Columns to one with 1 Column. As such, you will need to modify the `ColumnSpan` Property of your cells.

What you have drawn so far has 3 `Columns`, each with a `Width` of `GridLength *`. Start there.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
</Grid>
```

Next, we want to set up the `Rows`. It's better to make the number of Rows the largest that you'll need, which is by my count 6. If you set them all to `Auto`, then the empty `Rows` (in the Landscape orientation) will disappear.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
</Grid>
```

Now, to create some basic contents. I'm just going to create a bunch of different `StackPanel`s and name them what you have contained in them.

I am setting the default `Grid/Row` values to that of `Landscape`. I am also using two rows for the 'Second Row' (containing `StackPanel`s 1 and 2). Both `StackPanel`s will have a `RowSpan` of 2 to compensate.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>    
    <StackPanel Name="HeaderRow" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <StackPanel Name="Content" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <StackPanel Name="BlueSection" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <StackPanel Name="FooterRow" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Now we have a nice definition for your `Landscape` orientation. It will automatically size vertically based on the content within it as well, though you are free to do whatever minimum sizing you want.

Now that we've done this, we just need to create some `VisualStates` for our different sizes. In one `VisualState` we will be defining exactly what we've already done. In the other, we will be creating a new one. I am naming them 'Landscape' and 'Portrait' for now, but I suggest doing something like 'Mid' and 'Wide', and then defining which is used based on the `Bounds` given. I have omitted the previous definitions for the sake of space.

Technically, we don't need to include the `Landscape` definition, but I'm including it as an additional example.

**Note:** In the second picture, you have `StackPanel2` *below* `Footer`. I have reflected this below. If you need that changed, just change the row definitions of `StackPanel2` to `4` and of `Footer` to `5`.

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OrientationStates">
            <!-- What we've already defined -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel1">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel1">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <!-- Stack Panel 2 -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <!-- Content -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <! -- Blue Section -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="BlueSection">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="BlueSection">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="BlueSection">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <!-- Footer -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="Footer">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </VisualState>

            <!-- The New Section -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel1">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel1">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <!-- Stack Panel 2 -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="StackPanel2">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <!-- Content -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <! -- Blue Section -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="BlueSection">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)" Storyboard.TargetName="BlueSection">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Storyboard.TargetName="BlueSection">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                <!-- Footer -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)" Storyboard.TargetName="Footer">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="4"/>
                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

You're almost done. All you need left is for your `Page` to listen for `WindowSizeChanged` and respond to it! It needs to get a reference to your `Grid`. As such, I suggest adding `x:Name="ContentGrid"` or something similar to the base `Grid` definition. Such as:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
```

My example for `WindowSizeChanged` will assume you have done this.

```
private void WindowSizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs windowSizeChangedEventArgs)
{
    if (windowSizeChangedEventArgs.Size.Width < 800)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(ContentGrid, "Portrait", true);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(ContentGrid, "Landscape", true);
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Page`'s `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom`...

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.SizeChanged += WindowSizeChanged;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Window.Current.SizeChanged -= WindowSizeChanged;
}
```

**Make sure you remove the `SizeChanged` `event` handler on navigating from the page, otherwise your app will retain a copy of your page in memory indefinitely. This is how to create a fun memory leak.**

And that's it! On size changed, your main page will notify your Grid that it needs to reconfigure itself and it will do so in the way described. Obviously you won't be able to directly paste this in, but you should be able to use a lot of it. Make sure to change the `TargetNames` to your named controls.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate !!!
You solved my problem, that I was trying to solve from weeks, I searched blogs, videos and forums, but I couldn't get the exact answer , you actually solved the mystery of VisualStateManager, that was keep shaking my head ...

Thanks a lot and I am really grateful to you that you have actually coded the solution for me.

Comment: I also got some guidelines to create UI for Windows 8 app, this will be helpful for anybody who views this post later:<br>


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465349.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx